# Gitlab - Internally Open Source Project

Tags: git, permissions, gitlab, enterprise, gitlab-ee

For Gitlab enterprise, there is a way of making the project internal, so only known logged in users can *see* the project.

However is there a way of making a default permission/access level for anyone internal. I.e. make everyone internal have Developer access, for example. Essentially "internally open source" within the organization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in [this gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/public_access/public_access.html#internal-projects), the internal projects can be *seen* only by known logged users and these are all assigned the *guest* permission level.

If you need to grant a higher permission level to specific users (including all known users), you can use the [user group feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/) and [share your project with this group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/share_project_with_groups.html).

Comment: Yes, using a group is what I have resorted to now and it works reasonably easil.  but users still need to request access or be given access